# How to know that when the user goes offline in AgsXMPP?

Tags: xmpp, offline, agsxmpp

I am currently trying with agsXMPP library ,
i added users to a treenode on OnPresence event.
its works well, but when the other user goes offline i want to update the tree node,
for that i need his Offline Presence ,How i get result when a chat buddy goes offline ?

Answer (score 1):

When a buddy goes offline you get a OnPresence event with the Type of unavailable.

```
private void XmppCon_OnPresence(object sender, Presence pres)
{
    if (pres.Type == PresenceType.unavailable)
    {
        // user goes offline
    }
}
```